# Mockito, mission of method verify

Tags: java, mockito, verify

Could you please explain a mission of mockito method verify? Documentation says, that this method checks, whether the method was called. But can you give an example when it is really useful? Usually in test method we invoke a method and then... check, that we have invoked it right now? Sounds weird.

Comment: I don't forget... I don't know the right answer))) So, I can't desinform someone in future

Comment: @GhostCatsalutesMonicaC. - The OP does not _have_ to select an answer.  If they all add value, then upvotes will convey that point.  If no one answer stands out as more correct than the others, then it can be misleading to mark only one as "right".

Comment: @GhostCatsalutesMonicaC. Ok, but to me this seemed like a legitimate case where a single answer did not need to be chosen.  BTW, I notice that your comment requesting a selection has been deleted.  Odd.

Comment: @EJK Comments aren't meant to "stay forever". I try to do my part here ... when I notice that one of my own comments is "no longer needed" (for whatever reason) I will quickly delete it. And when I come across other peoples comment that are "no longer needed", I flag them accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To simplify... Let's say you are testing method **A** with certain parameters. What method A does is calls methods **B**, **C** and **D**.

With **Mockito.verify** you can test that methods B, C, D really are called. It even let's you specify more complex testing such as:

- *atLeast(1)*
- *atMost(10)*

It can really be useful when the method you are testing behaves differently based on parameters you call it with.

Comment: Did I correct understand you,
I have methods:
    public void method1() {
        method2();
    }

    public void method2() {
    }

And if I write
        myClass.method1();
        verify(mResource).method2();

- I gotta get green test line? But I have red. It says me:
Wanted but not invoked:
mResource.method2();

What am I doing a wrong way?

Answer (score 3):

It goes like this:

```
public class UnderTest {
  private Foo foo;

  public UnderTest(Foo foo) { this.foo = foo };

  public void bar() { foo.foo(); }
}
```

Now assume that you provide a *mocked* foo instance to UnderTest. And you want to be **sure** that `foo.foo()` is invoked when `bar()` is called.

Then you use **verify()** to ensure that the expected call took place.

In other words: tests need to *verify* method behavior. Ideally they do that by *asserting* on values returned by the method under test. But not all methods return something. Then you *might* verify your code by at least checking that certain expected calls on objects owned/passed to the class under test did occur. And then you need *verify()*!

Answer (score 2):

This type of check is often performed just to make sure that specific object was used using specified parameters. Let's assume You are testing business service that performs some action and also some kind of audit trail is being stored in DB during this process.

Storing that kind of info in DB was already tested somewhere else (separate unit-tests or some kind of external library is used), so You do not need checking whether audit data was stored properly. For the sake of Your test-case the information that this method was called is sufficient. And that's the use case for 'verify' method.

Answer (score 2):

> Usually in test method we invoke a method and then... check, that we have invoked it right now? Sounds weird.

You don't verify that you invoked a test method. You verify that as a result of whatever that test did, some dependency (that you have replaced with a mock) was called.

So for example, when testing a password checker method, you want to assert that in addition to rejecting the incorrect password it also calls some auditing backend system to register the failed login attempt. Your mock object would stand in for that backend system, and you can use it to verify that it ended up being called (and also with the proper parameters).

Answer (score 0):

Let's imagine that you have some DAO class which interacts with the database by plain JDBC. You have some method to write data in the database and want to unit test it. To do so, you probably mock `Connection` class. When you're writing in the database you will probably call `commit` method on this mock, but the return type of it is `void`, so you can't guarantee that that method invoked during your test. To solve such problems you can use `verify`.
Hope it helps!

Comment: does it mean that verify checks successful  
completion of method?

Comment: @MariaKarpikova, it just checks that the method was called.

Answer (score 0):

Methods return either something or `void`.
In unit test, as a method returns something, generally you want to mock its result with a specific value and check that the flow of the tested method goes on as it should.
It makes sense as if a method to mock returns something, generally you need its results : either in the next statement of the tested method or in the result returned by the tested method.

As a method returns nothing (`void`), things are different : you cannot mock its result.
But you can assert that this method is invoked and with expected parameters.

For example imagine a `PrinterService` class to print documents

```
public class PrintService{
 ...
  public void printMessage(String message){
    os.print(message);
  }
}
```

And suppose you need to isolate it during an unit test of another class.
Here the method to test :

```
public class PrintClient{
 ...
  PrintService printService;

  public void print(String message, PrinterParameters printerParameters...){
     ... // do some tasks
     ...
     printService.print(message);
    ...          
  }
}
```

`PrintService.print()` returns nothing.
So in the unit test of `PrintClient`, you don't want to mock the result of `PrintService.print()` as it doesn't have.
You want just to check that it was invoked with the `message` argument passed to 
to the `PrintClient` tested method.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) 
public class PrintClientTest{

    @Mock 
    PrintService printServiceMock;
    ...
    @Test
    pubic void print(){
      ... 
      String message = "my message";  
      PrintClient printClient = new PrintClient(printServiceMock);
      printClient.print(message, ...);
      //
      Mockito.verify(printServiceMock).print(message);
      ...
    }
}
```

Comment: @Thilo  Really sorry but I am not sure to get what you mean. I don't want to call the method on the mock object as I want only verify that the service is invoked with the good parameter  provided by the client that I unit test.

Comment: Ah, my bad, sorry, got confused by the missing @InjectMocks there.

Comment: @Florian Schaetz  No it is me. I think that I  probably bad chose the  naming. `PrintClient.print()` and `PrintService.print()` may be confusing. I added an explicit constructor to be clearer.